# how to move windows between desktop screens

Tags: desktop

I like to use three fingers swipe right and left to move between different screens. But how should i move currently opened windows to particular desktops of my liking?

Answer (score 3):

Open up Mission Control.

It can be found in your Applications folder or you can activate it with a 3-finger swipe up. This gives you an overview of your open windows and desktops. You can the drag and drop windows between desktops.

more info: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4689

Answer (score 0):

You can also pick up the window you want to move, drag it to the edge of the screen and hold it there until the next/previous desktop slides into view.